# Hierarchical / nested styles in LESS

Tags: css, less

For better readability and cleaner code, I'm using nested styles in LESS like this:

```
.item {
    .title {
        /* ... */
    }
    .content {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

The problem is the descendant selector it compiles to, e.g.:

```
.item .title {
    /* ... */
}
```

is supposedly really bad for performance. Is that still true for modern browsers? And if so, what's the alternative? (My aim here is organized code, I probably don't really need the descendant selector.)

Comment: It's not *really bad*. If there are any performance implications, they would be so small that they would be negligible. Modern browsers are optimized to handle this..

Comment: Why is it bad? The browser should always get minification CSS. For other people who edit code are LESS files with great readability.

Comment: You can use `& > .title`, which will be compiled to `.item > .title`. Child selectors may be a bit faster than descendant ones.

Comment: @Mardzis https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS#Avoid_the_descendant_selector.21
Minification doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know `.item .title` is the only way to select a `.title` inside a `.item` (`.item > .title` as mentioned by @Oriol possible also works in some situations). Less enables you to nested this relation.

When you don't need that relation, you should not nest it in your Less code too. Possible use comments to make clear that a group of selectors belongs to a certain other selector. Alternatively consider the BEM methodology, see http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/, then .item .title can be written as `item__title {}`.